# C LANGUAGE - How to read string, int and float from the same row of the same file.txt?

Tags: c

I have started studying C language at the university few weeks ago. I am learning the C language, but I'm stuck at reading stuffs from file! I'll do an example: Let's say I have a file called file.txt, and it contains:

```
Jack 7 8 7.5
John 5 6 5.5
```

I want to read Jack in a string, 7 and 8 in two integers and 7.5 in a float.. same for the second row.. How do I do that?

```
int main(){
    char file[15],name[15];
    int a,b;
    float c;
    FILE* f;
    scanf("%s",file);
    f=fopen(file,"r");
    if(f==NULL){
        printf("Error reading file.");
        return 1;
    }
while(){
}
```

How do I proceed now? I can't do `fscanf` because it won't read the entire row, If I do `fgets`, it will save all the row in one string, without making difference between string, integers and float..
PS: Sorry for bad english, it's not my first language.

Comment: One solution will be reading lines via `fgets()` and parse them via `sscanf()`.

Comment: If the names are always simple words with no spaces, then you can use scanf.

Comment: You can split the string with `strtok`

Comment: `while(fscanf(f, "%14s%d%d%f", name, &a, &b, &c) == 4) { /* printf result */ }` This will only work for a name that is a single word. As advised, `fgets()` and then `sscanf` is better.

Comment: regarding: `printf("Error reading file.");`   1) this is NOT the problem, the code has not tried to read the file.  2) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  3) when the error is from a C library function, should also output to `stderr` the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.   One excellent way to perform the above is: `perror( "fopen failed" );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will read them via `fscanf()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char file[15],name[15];
    int a,b;
    float c;
    FILE* f;
    scanf("%s",file);
    f=fopen(file,"r");
    if(f==NULL){
        printf("Error reading file.");
        return 1;
    }
    while(fscanf(f, "%14s%d%d%f", name, &a, &b, &c) == 4){
        /* do something */
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

But you say you can't do this because `fscanf()` won't read the entire row (it leaves the newline characters at the end of row in the input buffer).
Then, you can use `fgets()` and use `sscanf()` to parse the row.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char buffer[1024];
    char file[15],name[15];
    int a,b;
    float c;
    FILE* f;
    scanf("%s",file);
    f=fopen(file,"r");
    if(f==NULL){
        printf("Error reading file.");
        return 1;
    }
    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), f) != NULL){
        if (sscanf(buffer, "%14s%d%d%f", name, &a, &b, &c) == 4) {
            /* do something */
        } else {
            /* handle invalid line */
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: Was about to answer this with "look into scanf" but I see you did an excellent job of presenting the same information.  Thanks.

Comment: UV for `fgets()`.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s",file);`   This enable the user to enter more than a 14 character file name.  The result would be a buffer overflow and undefined behavior